# Version of Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, versioning

I have a Java based webapp which uses ~20 javascript files and CSS. As a standard practice, I have minified and bundled into groups which provided a lot of performance.

Now I wish to add versioning ability on top of this by computing the MD5 of each file. I could think of adding a TAG $$VERSION in every HTML file for each resource and then replace $$VERSION with the MD5 of that particular resource.

```
Ex: 

<style href="/css/editor.css?v=$$VERSION"></style>
<script src="/js/editor.js?v=$$VERSION"></script>
```

and then have a separate utility which does the task of replacement(for performance it can cache the resource -> MD5 mapping)

Other languages (like Ruby) provides this facility out of the box. but there isn't solution for Java based web applications. Is the above approach correct? If not please point me to other alternatives.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you're missing a quote after your script source.

Comment: Java based or Javascript based, or both?

Comment: I need a Java based solution.

Comment: @PeterRader I am using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML often is not-xml-like. For example the missing of quotas will be no problem. It is realy hard to reliable change the code.

You can handle css-files with the default jsp-interpreter by adding

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url>*.css</url>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url>*.js</url>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to the **web.xml**.

So you can define **/css/editor.css** and rewrite to your versioned one like this

```
<jsp:forward page="/css/editor.css?v=${mybean.getHash('editor.css')}" />
```

Comment: Is there any existing libraries to this in JSP?

Comment: Nope, i can write you a one-class-jar for this if you like?